# Accessing Response Object While Using WebForms Async/Await

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, async-await

I have a simple .net 4.5 webforms project that I am using to output the results of some service checks.  I have already created a service checking classes that are multi-threaded and awaitable (each check might take 1-3 seconds and I want them checked in parallel).  I want the result of each service check to be written to the web page and flushed as soon as it is determined (I don't care if the results are in order).  The service checker methods have been tested and work fine in a console application, but I'm having trouble porting it to a webforms app.

The code below somewhat works (very randomly).  Sometimes, it's perfect.  Other times, it "skips" displaying the results of one of the tests.  Other times, it mixes the display of the CSS style in with the results!  Mostly, though, it crashes on the Response.Flush line in CheckService stating "Overlapped I/O operation is in progress" and then it crashes.

How can I write the the web page response buffer when each check finishes and displays their results in a stable manner?

Here's the code for the aspx page...

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Async="true" AutoEventWireup="true" Inherits="ServiceMonitor._Default" Codebehind="Default.aspx.cs" %>
```

And here's the code behind...

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      Response.Write("<style type=\"text/css\">body {font-family: Arial;font-size: 10pt;}</style>");
      Response.Write("Beginning processing...<br/>");
      Response.Flush();
      RegisterAsyncTask(new PageAsyncTask(CheckServices));
  }

  protected async Task CheckServices()
  {
      Response.Write(string.Format("Starting checks at {0}<br/>", DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()));
      var tasks = new List<Task<ServiceStatus>>
      {
          Task.Run(() => CheckService("ServiceOne")),
          Task.Run(() => CheckService("ServiceTwo")),
          Task.Run(() => CheckService("ServiceThree"))
      };
      var checkResults = (await Task.WhenAll(tasks)).ToList();
      Response.Write(string.Format("Checking complete at {0}<br/>", DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()));
      Response.Flush();
  }

  public ServiceStatus CheckService(string serviceName)
  {
      var startTime = DateTime.Now;

      // Simulate a longer running process, by pausing for 1-3 seconds
      var random = new Random();
      var end = DateTime.Now + TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(random.Next(1000, 3000)); 
      while (DateTime.Now < end) { }

      var elapsedTime = (DateTime.Now - startTime).TotalSeconds;
      var service = new ServiceStatus {Name = serviceName, IsRunning = true};
      Response.Write(string.Format("Done with {0} in {1} seconds<br/>", service.Name, elapsedTime.ToString("N2")));
      Response.Flush();
      return service;
    }
}

public class ServiceStatus
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsRunning { get; set; }
}
```

FYI - The app isn't supposed to be pretty, hence the removal of standard HTML markup.  It also won't be accessed by many users (really just me) so IIS blocking isn't really a concern and the page should return back within 20-30 seconds.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is that you're trying to access the request context (i.e., `Reponse.Write`) from a random background thread (i.e., `Task.Run`).

The ideal solution is to go async all the way. By this, I mean to make your service checkers asynchronous but *not* multithreaded. If they're implemented using an API ping, then you can check out `HttpClient` for the implementation.

Once they're asynchronous, the `CheckService` method will be async as well:

```
public async Task<ServiceStatus> CheckServiceAsync(string serviceName)
{
  var startTime = DateTime.Now;

  // Simulate a longer running process, by pausing for 1-3 seconds
  var random = new Random();
  var waitTime = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(random.Next(1000, 3000));
  await Task.Delay(waitTime);

  var elapsedTime = (DateTime.Now - startTime).TotalSeconds;
  var service = new ServiceStatus {Name = serviceName, IsRunning = true};
  Response.Write(string.Format("Done with {0} in {1} seconds<br/>", service.Name, elapsedTime.ToString("N2")));
  Response.Flush();
  return service;
}
```

And it can be called *concurrently*, without *multithreading*:

```
protected async Task CheckServicesAsync()
{
  Response.Write(string.Format("Starting checks at {0}<br/>", DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()));
  var tasks = new List<Task<ServiceStatus>>
  {
    CheckService("ServiceOne"),
    CheckService("ServiceTwo"),
    CheckService("ServiceThree")
  };
  var checkResults = (await Task.WhenAll(tasks)).ToList();
  Response.Write(string.Format("Checking complete at {0}<br/>", DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()));
  Response.Flush();
}
```

Comment: Stephen, thank you very much for the assistance.  This looks promising but it will take a bit for me to do some refactoring to do testing on my real checkers.  However, I do have one question for you... how can tasks run "concurrently without multithreading"?  I assumed that only one operation can run on a single thread at a time.  If so, how can an application do more than one thing at a time and not be multithreaded?

Comment: @bigmac: It's because truly asynchronous operations do not require threads to run. I describe this [on my blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html), but take an HTTP ping as an example: once the HTTP request is sent, there's no need for a thread to hang around just waiting for the response. So you can use `async`/`await` to start three requests and then use `await Task.WhenAll` to (asynchronously) wait for them all to complete. No threads are blocked, yet the code is doing multiple operations concurrently.

Comment: just to let you know I completed my refactoring and your code works great!  Thanks for the help!